# Angular2 component constructor didn't called

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

my demo app component's constructor did not called at app start:

demo component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-page',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor run');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('oninit run');
  }
}
```

routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'demo',
    component: DemoComponent ,
    resolve: {
      data: DemoResolverService
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

resolver service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DemoResolverService implements Resolve<SomeData> {
  constructor(private logic: demoService) {}

  resolve(): Observable<SomeData> {
    console.log('dataresolver run');

    return this.logic.getAll();
  }
}
```

The resolver service constructor run successfully, and before navigation its called too.
But the component not constructor not running.
Is there any idea why its stop working?
Thanks

Comment: Can u share it in stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaShrama  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sis7eb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnay5f?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

[Router-outlet](https://angular.io/guide/router) in Angular works as a placeholder which is used to load the different components dynamically based on the activated component or current route state